# How can we test disabling website cache on iOS device?

Tags: ios, caching

I am disabling website cache on my browser on an iOS device but I am not able to test whether the website cache has been disabled or not on the browser. 
Can any one suggest a way that I can test this.

Answer (score 0):

For disabling cache on Safari on iOS device

1. Open Settings
2. Navigate to Safari > Advanced
3. Enable Web Inspector
4. Switch back to Safari and load a web page

For disabling cache on an iOS app if you are using browser components (UIWebView etc):

ObjC:

```
// Remove and disable all URL Cache, but doesn't seem to affect the memory
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setDiskCapacity:0];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] setMemoryCapacity:0];
```

Swift:

```
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().diskCapacity = 0
NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().memoryCapacity = 0
```

Comment: Is there a way we can test the above code manually or using a tool just to make sure that the cache is getting disabled in the browser.